# Compiling specific sub module to an older java version

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi model project :

```
parent
---shared.  (java8)
---module1 (java8)
---module2. (java17)
```

In the **parent** I set the following maven compiler plugin settings :

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

**In module 1 I set the compiler target and source to 1.8 (Java 8)**. I build the parent (with JDK17) and as a result all the sub modules were also build. I opened the jar and checked one of the file to make sure that the files in module1 are compatible with java8 :

```
$ jar xf module1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
$ file MyClass.class
MyClass.class: compiled Java class data, version 52.0 (Java 1.8)
```

Up until now everything looks good. When going over the documentation of maven I found the following note :

> Note: Merely setting the target option does not guarantee that your code actually runs on a JRE with the specified version. The pitfall is unintended usage of APIs that only exist in later JREs which would make your code fail at runtime with a linkage error. To avoid this issue, you can either configure the compiler's boot classpath to match the target JRE, or use the Animal Sniffer Maven Plugin to verify your code doesn't use unintended APIs, or better yet use the release option supported since JDK 9. In the same way, setting the source option does not guarantee that your code actually compiles on a JDK with the specified version. To compile your code with a specific JDK version, different than the one used to launch Maven, refer to the Compile Using A Different JDK example.

[src](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

So does that mean that there is a chance that module1 will throw runtime errors for other java8 apps because of compatibility issues ?

In addition, According to [this post](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html), since version 9 Java keeps compatibility only 3 versions backwards. Does that relevant only if my source and target were different (maven.compiler.source/target)? Or it might be relevant since I compile my project with JDK17 while the code is written Java 9.

It will be great if someone can make it clearer for me.

Comment: First I would suggest to use `<maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>` in your parent. In the module you would like to build with a different target just set the property like `<maven.compiler.release>8</maven.compiler.release>`... Do not use `source` and `target` are simply wrong in such a case...

Comment: As i understood, `maven.compiler.release `is a available from java 9, If i'll use it how it will effect the java8 module ?

Comment: Yes the release options is available since JDK9+. `If i'll use it how it will effect the java8 module` I don't understand that sentence?

Comment: `maven.compiler.release` is available since JDK9+. Can  I use it even if my module is using Java 8?  My code is compiled with JDK17 but the code itself is written as a java 8 app.

Comment: If you use JDK17 than you can of course build code which runs on a JVM 8 yes. `but the code itself is written as a java 8 app` ? Means of course you can only use api etc. which are only available from JDK8...

Comment: `maven.compiler.release` is available in JDK17 regardless of the Java version you specify.

Comment: Is there a way to validate that my app is using only java 8 apis  ? What can you tell about the note that I added from maven's documentation ?